# How to reseve space at the end of each page in SQLite database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to encrypt an SQLite3 database using [pysqlsimplecipher](https://github.com/bssthu/pysqlsimplecipher). When I try to encrypt it, it gives an error:

```
raise RuntimeError('needs reserved space at the end of each page.')
RuntimeError: needs reserved space at the end of each page.
```

I Don't know how to do that. I'm using DB browser for sqlite. Is there any SQL statement I should execute, any setting i should change in DB browser  or any python function from its SQLite module to reserve space at the end of each page? And how much of space would be enough?

Or any workaround? Its a part of larger program so the constraint here is that I should use python in order to encrypt. However,I can use any method to reserve space as it had to be done only once.

My platform is windows 8.1 and python version is 3.6 x32. If that matters.

I'm asking about a pythonic way or an SQL statement to do it. 
I've found an [answer using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201975/how-to-create-database-with-reserved-bytes) already but that's in c++. I don't know much about c++
I've read that you've to compile sqlite in order to use with  c++. I don't know about it. I would appreciate if someone posts the entire code snippet to do it using c++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create database with reserved bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201975/how-to-create-database-with-reserved-bytes)

Comment: No, the answer there is about c/c++ :sqlite3_test_control(SQLITE_TESTCTRL_RESERVE, sqlite3 *db, int N)
I'm asking about an SQL or pythonic way.

Comment: The `sqlite3_test_control` function can only be used with an **empty** database. Anyway, you could probably call it from python using the `ctypes` module.

Comment: Thank you ekhumoro. Please clarify 'empty' ; I should delete tuples or entire tables(create new database)?

Comment: By "empty", I mean a new database. You will need to use `ctypes` to create the new database, so you can get a pointer to it that can be passed to the `sqlite3_test_control` function (i.e. for the `sqlite3 *db` argument). After this, you can transfer all the data from the old db to the new db using whatever method you like. If you google "ctypes sqlite3", you should find lots of example code to get you started (e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44437521/984421)).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/bssthu/pysqlsimplecipher/blob/master/README.md) you linked to says:

> Needs reserved space at the end of each page of the database file.
>
> Otherwise, use sqlcipher to encrypt.
>
> **Encrypt with sqlcipher**
>
> - Open plain db
>
>   ```
>   ./sqlcipher plain.db
>   ```
> - Encrypt to enc.db
>
>   ```
>   ATTACH DATABASE 'enc.db' as encrypted key 'testkey';
>   SELECT sqlcipher_export('encrypted');
>   DETACH DATABASE encrypted;
>   ```

Answer (score 1):

So after days of research and trying tons of methods. I was successful in doing it. The method sqlite3_test_control(SQLITE_TESTCTRL_RESERVE, sqlite3 *db, int N) does not work any more. So I Used a HEX editor to change the specific byte used for indicating how much of space is to be reserved at the end of each page in a sqlite Database. Here Goes:

1- Create an empty database: do not create any table or anything yet. create and save an sqlite database file.

2- Use a Hex editor to change the byte at offset 20. It will be 00 Which means no bytes are reserved. So for instance ,if you want to reserve 36 bytes. change the value of byte at offset 20 to '24' (36 when converted to HEX).

3-check the bytes at offset 105 and 106. Their value indicate the starting position of content area. if reserved space is 0 The value will be page size.
For example in this case its 0400 which is 1024 in decimal. Now subtract the bytes you previously set to reserve; 36. 1024-36 =988. In HEX its 03DC. 
Set the value at 105 and 106 offset to 03DC. Save It and Now you are good to go.
Check the  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djHkF.png) i've underlined the concerned bytes and settings of editor.

I needed to use [pysqlsimplecipher](https://github.com/bssthu/pysqlsimplecipher/wiki) for encryption and decryption of database which requires some bytes to be reserved at the end of each page.
Hope it helps someone.